# How to identify selected tab in SelectedTabChangeListener?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I want perform specific action when user selects one of the tabs.

```java
final TabSheet tabs = new TabSheet();
tabs.addTab(a, "a");
```

The following code always outputs `null`:

```java
tabs.addTab(b, "b");
System.out.println(a.getCaption());
tabs.addSelectedTabChangeListener(event -> {
    System.out.println(event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab().getCaption());
    System.out.println(event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab().getId());
});
```

Comment: I can't immagine why `getSelectedTab()` would return the tab content... but, how about using `if (tabs.getTab(tabs.getSelectedTab()) == a) { ... }`?

Comment: Apologies, `a` in your example is the tab content, so the actual code should be similar to `Tab aTab = tabs.addTab(a, "a"); if (tabs.getTab(tabs.getSelectedTab()) == aTab) { ... }`. Or, if you don't need to actually do anything with your tab, just check whether the content of the selected tab is the one you want `a == tabs.getSelectedTab()`. I'll add  a reply to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to understand the reasoning behind `getSelectedTab()` returning the tab content instead of the actual tab instance, but you have at least the following 2 options:

- if you want to do something to the actual tab instance, you can get it using the selected tab content
- if you don't care about the tab and you only need to know that a certain tab was selected, you can check the selected tab content against the expected content

**Code:**

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.CheckBox;
import com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class TabSelectionComponent extends VerticalLayout {
    public TabSelectionComponent() {
        // tab contents
        Button aButton = new Button("A");
        Button bButton = new Button("B");

        // tabs and tab sheet
        TabSheet tabs = new TabSheet();
        TabSheet.Tab aTab = tabs.addTab(aButton, "A");
        TabSheet.Tab bTab = tabs.addTab(bButton, "B");

        // checkboxes for selection visualization
        CheckBox byTabInstance = new CheckBox("Check by tab instance");
        byTabInstance.setEnabled(false);
        CheckBox byTabContent = new CheckBox("Check by tab content");
        byTabContent.setEnabled(false);

        tabs.addSelectedTabChangeListener(event -> {
            // the selected tab matches the expected one
            byTabInstance.setValue(tabs.getTab(tabs.getSelectedTab()) == aTab);

            // the selected content matches the expected one 
            byTabContent.setValue(tabs.getSelectedTab() == aButton);
        });

        // add components to the UI
        addComponents(tabs, byTabContent, byTabInstance);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: vaadin verify selected tab]

Answer (score 0):

The following code works but it doesn't seem to be particularly *nice*:

```java
final Tab b = tabs.addTab(b, "b");
System.out.println(a.getCaption());
tabs.addSelectedTabChangeListener(event -> {
    final String connectorId = event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab().getConnectorId();
    final String bTabConnectorId = logoutTab.getComponent().getConnectorId();
    if(connectorId.equals(bTabConnectorId)) {
        System.out.println("selected"); // prints if selected tab == b
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ok: `event.getTabSheet().getSelectedTab().getId()`

You just need to explicitly set the id for the components yourself after creating them: `a.setId("id_a"); b.setId("id_b"));` otherwise `getId()` returns `null` whic is the default.

Might be good idea also to take a look at `setData()` if in need to use something else than plain string.

> Sets the data object, that can be used for any application specific
>   data. The component does not use or modify this data.